# Is cron command wget -q create file at server?

Tags: cron, wget

Currently, I have one php function which is running with cron. It's the function to check the timestamp and close the topic. To check the timestamp and make live update, I have to use cron. I run cron with this command

```
wget -q http://www.example.com/program/timecheck
```

Everything seems working perfectly, so I didn't check my server for quite long. But today, I checked and found out that there are more than 500,000 of files called timecheck are created at root directory.

I checked through the code and it's sure that there's no code for creating the file.

What I would like to know is, is it because of the wget -q command ? If that's what command should i use to execute the url ?

Thanks for your help.

With Regards,

Comment: wget fetches a file by default, unless you tell it not to. `-q` is just "quiet", which means it won't print progress upates as it fetches the file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming this is a Linux-like OS,

```
wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.example.com/program/timecheck
```

The file is the output from wget. This option (`-O`) tells it to write the output to `/dev/null`, thus discarding it.

Comment: `wget -O NUL ...` on Windows.

Comment: is the option 'O' = ZERO, or Capital O

Answer (score 1):

yes, by default wget will save a file and it will create append version to file downloaded to avoid force replace

`-q` is just disable the verbose message

you can override this with :-

```
wget -O /tmp/log.file ${url} // this will always replace the /tmp/log.file
```

Comment: Actually `-q` will quiet meaning it will Turn off Wget's output.